# Setting http headers RSpec 2.4 / Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, webrat

I am getting started with RSpec. I have a new rails 3 app which uses the HTTP_ACCEPT_HEADER or the request 2 letter subdomain to set the application language and redirect accordingly. I am successfully testing my redirection code using Cucumber.

Now I want to write my controller specs and I need to set the request subdomain before my test.

In my cucumber steps, I can specify:

```
header 'HTTP_HOST', 'es.mysite.local'
visit '/'
```

But when I try to do this in a spec file

```
header 'HTTP_HOST', 'es.mysite.local'
get 'index'
```

I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: header 'HTTP_HOST', "es.mysite.local"
 LoadError:
   no such file to load -- action_controller/integration
```

Any clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
request.env['HTTP_HOST'] = 'es.mysite.local'
get 'index'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had already tried that, but I now realize that another code example was reaching my debug point first.

Comment: Thanks! It works today with Rails 3.0.7 and avoided me to put full urls with subdomains everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is correct, and in general the name of the header should be in all caps, prefixed with HTTP_, and separated with underscores. For example the "If-Modified-Since" header can be set with:

```
request.env['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] = Time.now.httpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting an HTTP header for every request in rspec is also possible. Add to your spec_helper inside the `RSpec.configure do |config|` block:

```
config.before(:each) do |x|
    x.request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = 'de-CH,de;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'
end
```